# Howto show absolute number in Apexcharts pie chart

Tags: apexcharts

The pie chart I created with Apexcharts shows relative (percentage) numbers at the circle (like the "99.9%" in the screenshot below).

Instead of the relative number I'd like to show the absolute value like what's in the tooltip (see example: "6752").

[image: Apexcharts Tooltip shows absolute number]

I tried a formatter function with signature `function(value, {seriesIndex,dataPointIndex,w})`, but `value` is the relative value (e.g. 99.9), `dataPointIndex` is undefined, `seriesIndex` is always 1 and `w` contains the whole chart config without being specific to this slice of the pie.

How can I show absolute numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right strategy, but probably not the right formatter. The one you need is [`dataLabels.formatter`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/datalabels/#formatter):

```js
let options = {
  series: [10, 20, 15],
  chart: {
    width: 350,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3'],
  dataLabels: {
    formatter: (val, { seriesIndex, w }) => w.config.series[seriesIndex] // <--- HERE
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```